# Create UIView Class programmatically with passing an array from UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, swift

I have a custom class for a UIView that contains multiple UIButtons. When I create the UIView in the UIViewController, I want to pass an array (full of titles for the UIButtons) from UIViewController to the UIView.

In UIViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
     var titles:Array = ["title 1", "title 2", "title 3", "title 4"]
     var buttonsLeft: buttonsView = buttonsView(titlesLocal: titles) 
     //rest of code
}
```

In buttonsView (my UIView class)

```
class buttonsView: UIView {

    var titlesLocal:Array<String> = Array()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: You need to create a new initializer method that takes an array as argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom view define New initialiser with array of titles as argument as follows:

```
class buttonsView: UIView {

    var titles : Array<String>?

    init(titlesLocal atitles : Array<String>)
    {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
        self.titles = atitles
    }
}
```

To avoid the error this build error `ViewController.Type does not have a member named 'titles'`.  In your view controller, You cannot assign the `var` variable to another in instance variable instead of that, You need to define the array as constant using `let` outside of the class as follows:

```
let titles : Array<String> = ["title 1", "title 2", "title 3", "title 4"]

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
     var buttonsLeft: buttonsView = buttonsView(titlesLocal: titles) 
     //rest of code
}
```

As you are creating string of array. It is good that if you specify the type of the Array explicitly.

This may help you!

Answer (score 1):

```
class buttonsView: UIView {

    var titles: Array<String>

    init(titles: Array<String>) {
       self.titles = titles
       super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that makes perfect sense that I need to initialize it. But it is still giving me the same error in my UIViewController saying "UIViewController.type does not have a member named "titles"

Comment: Ah, that's because you can't reference `titles` where you define `buttonsLeft` because it technically doesn't yet exist. You probably want to set `buttonsLeft` in the `init` method instead.

Comment: Sorry it was another mistake causing that. It is now accepting variable. Thanks again!